# Why is there a thick border around my document when I export?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, export

I don't see why this is happening. It doesn't matter what size the document is, or how many times I restart the program, or changes in the bleeds, there are no objects outside the artboard. It only doesn't show up when I save for web.. please help?
[image: Here I am exporting a sticker design and there is an eyesore of a white border around it. It's not even visible in the actual document]

Comment: Instead of having us try to guess what the problem may be try to explain, what export option you use, what your object stack looks like etc. Then your more likely to get help.

Answer (score 1):

As [@Billy](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/users/89608/billy-kerr) mentioned, a raster effect is applied, and AI considers the wider area of the effect to be also artwork.

Try exporting the PNG using the "Save for Web" panel and make sure the "Clip to Artboard" option is checked. This will force the PNG size to be identical to your artboard size, cropping out whatever hangs outside the artboard.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have a Rasterize effect applied. I can see it in the Appearance panel.

When you added the Rasterize effect did notice a value in the Add Around Object field? If there was a number in there, this will add a transparent border around the object when you do *File > Export Selection*. Try setting it to 0 instead.

[image]